# Spring data JPA + TABLE_PER_CLASS polymorphic save one to many

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, table-per-class

I have these classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "garage")
class Garage {

    @Id
    private String id;


    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "garage_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private List<Vehicle> vehiclesList;
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
abstract class Vehicle {

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "cars")
class Car extends Vehicle {

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "trucks")
class Truck extends Vehicle {

}
```

I am using cascade all.

When I am trying to persist them. 
I get: SqlError, No table 'vehicle'

I want to clarify that I am always persisting a garage with one type of vehicles

So when I hit `garageRepository.save(garage)`  I expect the child table (either car or truck) to be populated. and the garage_id will be the new garage.

How can this be done?

Regards,
Ido

Answer (score 1):

I believe this cannot be achieved with `InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS` strategy.

Reason being, with TABLE_PER_CLASS, spring-data-jpa(Hibernate) will create two tables in Database. `cars` and `trucks`. And there will be no `Vehicle` table.
But since you have  `private List<Vehicle> vehiclesList;` in your Garage class, spring-data searches for Vehicle table and hence you see this error.

Couple of suggestions.

This can be achieved by.
1. `InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE` (There will be only one table. `Vehicle`) 
2. `InheritanceType.JOINED` (There will be three tables `cars`, `trucks`, `vehicle`)

or

You can change the type in Garage to some concrete type like Car or Truck(which doesn't make sense)